# Função com retardo

Tags: html, jquery

Meu cenario é o seguinte, tenho um link e gostaria que apos clicar nele apos 3 segundos submeter um formulario. estou tentando o seguinte

```
 <a href="" target="_blank" id="acionabotao">Link</a>

 <form method="post" action="acao.php">
 <input name="" value="">
 <button type="submit" id="clickatrasado">
 </form>

 $("#acionabotao").click(function(){
 setTimeout(function() {
 $("#clickatrasado").trigger('click');
 }, 1000);
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o método `on()` de jQuery e pegue o form pelo `id` desta forma basta usar `submit()`

```js
$('#envia-form').on('click', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#form-target').submit()
    }, 3000)
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" target="_blank" id="envia-form">Link</a>

 <form id="form-target" method="post" action="./?">
     <input type="hidden" name="oculto" value="xxxx">
 </form>
```